# Is it possible to set different retry policies based on recipient address in Postfix?

Tags: postfix

I have a postfix server handling different types of email traffic. These types are aligned by the recipient mailbox. While I can set a default policy for retries interval (mnimial|maximal_backoff_time, queue_run_delay) and expiry (maximal_queue_lifetime), there are some specific addresses where I want the email server to give up much sooner (notably the maximal_queue_lifetime).

How do I do that?

(preferably without routing these emails via an additional server)